# Is there a proof that any pure two-qubit Partially entangled state lies somewhere in between a separable and maximally entangled state?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, stabilizer-state

Intuitively this seems true, but is there a proof of the following:

We have two-qubit pure state. Given a Partially entangled state (PES) $|P\rangle$ we can always find a separable state $|S\rangle$, a Maximally entangled state (MES) $|M\rangle$ and a hamiltonian R s.t.
$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}R}|S\rangle = |M\rangle$$
and
$$e^{i\theta R}|S\rangle = |P\rangle$$
$$\theta < \frac{\pi}{4}$$

In other words given a PES $|P\rangle$ can we redefine the basis in such a way that $|P\rangle$ will lay between two states of the stabilizer set (for the newly redefined basis), one separable, another MES. The stabilizers obviously connected by $\pi/2$ (angle halves when we put it into the exponent) rotation through some Hamiltonian of the form $\sigma_a \otimes \sigma_b$ where sigma matrices are also defined in the new basis and $a$ might or might not be equal to $b$. So then $|P\rangle$ is obtainable from the seprable state by a rotation using the same Hamiltonian, just by a smaller angle.

I hope my wording is clear enough - I am trying to translate from the language of Geometric Algebra into the language of Matrix mechanics :)

Comment: Can you spell out acronyms?

Comment: I would take a look at the Schmidt decomposition, it seems at first glance to be relevant

Comment: I understand the question, but not the discussion below it. Can you make this more precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

To prove this, write your "target state" $\lvert P\rangle$ in a Schmidt decomposition,
$$
\lvert P\rangle = \sum_{i=0,1} \lambda_i \lvert a_i\rangle\lvert b_i\rangle\ .
\tag{1}
$$
You can now construct a Hamiltonian $H$ which in the Schmidt basis acts as a Pauli $Y$, and arbitrarily on their orthogonal complement.

(More specifically, choose an ONB $\{\lvert a_0, b_0\rangle,\lvert a_1 b_1\rangle,\lvert v_2\rangle,\lvert v_3\rangle\}$ and define $H$ as
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i& 0 \\&&1 \\&&&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
-- though any matrix in the lower block will do.)

This Hamiltonian will generate a rotation
$$
e^{i\theta Y} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}
$$
on that subspace. In particular, if applied to the state $\lvert a_0\rangle\lvert b_0\rangle$, it will traverse the entire family in Eq. (1), from the product state $\lvert a_0\rangle\lvert b_0\rangle$ to the maximally entangled state $\lvert a_0\rangle\lvert b_0\rangle+\lvert a_1\rangle\lvert b_1\rangle$, with your target state reached somewhere along the trajectory.

Comment: By Pauli Y you mean Hamiltonian of the form $Y \otimes Y$ or something of the form $Y \otimes I$? It seems that the form of the first one seems more relevant to nome between separable and entangled states. Actually making the calculation $-Y \otimes X$ or $-X \otimes Y$ seem to be the relevant hamiltonians.

Comment: I have edited. (Note that it is $\oplus$, not $\otimes$.)